# Error when installing jquery for node js

Tags: jquery, .net, node.js, installation

I am trying to install jquery on node js. I did this:

```
npm install jquery
```

And the result is:

```
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
please add the "/m" switch.
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe".
 To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visua
l Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it
is installed elsewhere.  [C:\Users\Blah\node_modules\jquery\n
ode_modules\contextify\build\binding.sln]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\
npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:789:
12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modu
les\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Blah\node_modules\jquery\node_modules\co
ntextify
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.18
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.10.9
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! weird error 1
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the NPM Read Me, located [here](https://npmjs.org/package/jquery), it very clearly states that:

> DOES NOT WORK ON WINDOWS
>
> Many people are having problems getting this module to work on windows. The failure has to do with building contextify on window. It seems to be a windows environment issue. I don't have access to a windows machine so I cannot explore working through the windows install process. If you figure out how to build contextify on windows please send me working instructions!

There are several issues posted on its github page, [One](https://github.com/coolaj86/node-jquery/issues/45), [Two](https://github.com/coolaj86/node-jquery/issues/28), and [so on](https://github.com/coolaj86/node-jquery/search?q=windows&source=cc&type=Issues).  From a cursory glance at the issues and replies, it seems like it may be a challenge to get this working---but that it may be possible.  Your best bet is to start reading into the issues.